# How to modify the port apache2 is running on for each virtualhost using NamedVirtualHosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

My currently working apache config has everything running on port 80 (the usual) but I'm adding a node proxy to the front-end and this will listen on 80 and forward to other web servers based on the host requested.

At this time my httpd.conf file is empty, the ports.conf file looks like the below

```
NameVirtualHost *.80
Listen 80
```

inside my sites-available I have config file named "blog" -that file has the specific vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com:80
    DocumentRoot /www/blog.mysite.com/current/static
```

What should I modify if I just want to have apache working as it does now -except on port 9000?

The apache information is listed below -fresh install on Ubuntu 12.04

```
root@mybox:/etc/apache2# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
```

**UPDATE 1**

If I change each vhost and the ports.conf from :80 to :9000 and restart -apache won't serve anything on that port (note -port 80 still serves everything as you'd expect)

Do I need to modify the line *.80 in the files? if so to what? 127.0.0.1:9000 or ?

**UPDATE 2**

If I modify the NameVirtualHost to be *:9000 in all my vhosts / ports.conf I get the error below

```
root@mybox:/etc/apache2/sites-available# service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                      [Sat Jul 21 12:24:56 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 9000, the first has precedence
[Sat Jul 21 12:24:56 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 9000, the first has precedence
[Sat Jul 21 12:24:56 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting [Sat Jul 21 12:24:57 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 9000, the first has precedence
[Sat Jul 21 12:24:57 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 9000, the first has precedence
[Sat Jul 21 12:24:57 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Comment: Just changing 80 to 9000 does work. If your NameVirtualHost above is as it's written in yout conf file then it's wrong it should be  NameVirtualHost *:80 (or 9000). Do you see any error messages when you restart or in your logs ?

Comment: It looks like you missed an 80 somewhere. I just did this on a Ubuntu VM and it works exactly as expected.

Comment: You are correct sir -a simple grep found that my apache2.conf file had the original *:80 configuration (thanks for your time & patience)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just change all occurrences of `80` to `9000` and then restart your webserver.

```
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straightforward, change all occurrences of `80` to `9000`. When configuring your proxy, you just need to point it towards port 9000.

After you made your changes, do not forget to restart your apache server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

Add:

```
export VHOST_PORT_HTTP=9000
```

to /etc/apache2/envvars

Change:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

to

```
NameVirtualHost *:${VHOST_PORT_HTTP}
Listen ${VHOST_PORT_HTTP}
```

in /etc/apache2/ports.conf

and at the top of each of your vhosts, use:

```
<VirtualHost *:${VHOST_PORT_HTTP}>
```

Then you can control the HTTP port of all vhosts at the same time by changing the value in /etc/apache2/envvars and restarting. Handy if you need to bypass the proxy in a hurry.